# Can Network Admin Make changes to site if I've accessed the site in edit mode?

Tags: web-application

I connect to the Internet via a neighbor's wireless router (not a guest connection).

Windows 10: I don't share files or printer. Domain, private, public network: firewall is on. Scan = no issues.

I have a G Suite account to build sites. Site is published. Sharing options are secure. No other authorized users at this point.

Support asked for the URL of site builder in edit mode.

Two days later, many unauthorized changes to published Google site.
Is it possible for admin of neighbor's network to access or edit site if it's in edit mode?

Is it possible for the support person to use URL to access or edit site IF I have the site open in edit mode? Obviously, I can pull up the site in another browser screen, so wondered why support person with the link would be unable to do so.

Attempting to keep up with all the crazy, strange changes is eating my lunch. Need to ID the origin.

Comment: What support? Google support?

Comment: What "support"? Are you sure you contacted Google support and not a scammer?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure it was Google. I work with the support via G Suite.

Answer (score 1):

A network owner *can* (but is very unlikely to in a home network) see every byte that goes over their network.  However, the connection to Google Sites is encrypted through TLS (HTTPS). Those bytes would look like meaningless gibberish to them.

It is extremely unlikely that they gained access to your account simply by you connecting through their network, since Google is very good about this type of security.

The URL of a site's edit mode also does not contain sensitive account information. It may identify the account, as it identifies the site, but that is not enough by itself to gain access.

If the support person gained access, they did it with more information than the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response.

Comment: As you've stated, Google's reputation in regards to security is excellent. I use a 14 character access code that I change every couple of months.That & the fact that I transferred to the moon where the population is one. (Actually W. Texas -- but not much difference.) NO one accesses my computer. Based on your comments, I scanned each Google chant transcript  in hopes of identifying something I might have shared. There isn't anything else. .  Are the odds slim for identifying the culprit? Is it best to change the site builder & begin again? Suggestions?

Comment: Note: I changed my password immediately after seeing the unauthorized changes.

Comment: My general suggestion for any suspected compromised account is: Change that password. If it's a reused password, then change it **everywhere** and start using a password manager to generate truly random, long passwords that are unique for every site.  Set up 2-factor authentication, such as using the Google Authenticator app available on both Android and Apple phones. -- As far as this, specifically, the next step may be to report the site as compromised to Google.

Comment: Thank you Ghedipunk. I do use a unique 12-14 character password for each site I generate with  a calculator and 2-factor authentication. I'll capture some history and send it to Google. Thank you!